# tkinter opencv and numpy in windows with python2.7

Tags: python, windows, opencv, numpy, tkinter

I want to use "tkinter", "opencv" (cv2) and "numpy" in windows(8 - 64 bit and x64) with python2.7 - the same as I have running perfectly well in Linux (Elementary and DistroAstro) on other machines. I've downloaded the up to date Visual Studio and C++ compiler and installed these, as well as the latest version of PIP following error messages with the first attempts with PIP and numpy

- first I tried winpython, which already has numpy present but this comes without tkinter, although openCV would install. I don't want to use qt.
- so I tried vanilla Python, which installs to Python27. Numpy won't install with PIP or EasyInstall (unless it takes over an hour -same for SciPy), and the -.exe installation route for Numpy bombs becausee its looking for Python2.7 (not Python27). openCV won't install with PIP ("no suitable version")
- extensive searches haven't turned up an answer as to how to get a windows Python 2.7.x environment with all three of numpy, tkinter and cv2 working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it with .whl files. Download them, copy to C:\python27\Scripts and then open "cmd" and navigate to that folder with "cd\" etc. Once there run:

pip install numpy-1.10.1+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

for example.

In IDLE I then get:

import numpy

numpy.**version**

'1.10.1'

Answer (score 0):

small remark: WinPython has tkinter, as it's included by Python Interpreter itself